# Romano circuitikz style not compatible with flipflop

Tags: circuitikz

I'd like to use the romano circuitikz style for drawings with analog and digital components. However, I encounter compilation problems when I insert a flipflop.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzloadstyle{romano}
\tikzset{romano circuit style}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[flipflop SR,anchor=bpin 1](FF){};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The compilation error is: `` ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `f' or `fl' (in '1.0 flipflops/thick ness\pgf@circ@Rlen '). See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation. ``

Commenting out the `\ctikzloadstyle{romano}` and `\tikzset{romano circuit style}` produces the output, though obviously not in the intended style. Interestingly, I've not encountered problems with other logic gates, just the flipflop.

Any ideas what I'd need to change/add?

Comment: Fixed in the released 1.2.6 version. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the style file (ctikzstyle-romano.tex) at the flip-flops section, commas were missing at the end of each line.

```
% flip-flops
flipflops/scale=1.0,
flipflops/thickness=2.0,
%
```

I've solved the issue by placing the (adapted) *.sty manually in the same folder, and using input{..}. Styles were downloaded from https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/

Comment: I would be useful to make an issue about this at the github repository (https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues), so the maintainer Romano Giannetti (user @Rmano here on TeX.SE) can fix the problem.

Comment: @Marijn thanks! Noticed and fix on its way: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/463